# Core data entity attribute values to NSMutableArray iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I am using this code to fetch the core data results:

```
-(void)getData {

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Favouritesdata" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[request setFetchBatchSize:20];

[request setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"licenseplate" ascending:NO];

NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sort, nil];

[request setSortDescriptors:newArray];

NSError *error;
results = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"results::::: %@", results);

[self setLicensePlateArray:results];

[self.favouritesTable reloadData];

}
```

Here in this entity Favouritesdata, I have an attribute with the name of license plate, I want to get this attribute values to NSMutableArray.

How can I get these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSPredicate and directly get the value by passing the predicate in the request. Refer this link for more information http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html

Comment: difficult to understand for beginners ... any tutorial or example code

Comment: refer this link and go to saving and loading section were you will find somr coredata tutorial. For NSFetchController tutorial will help. http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Comment: NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[request setEntity:entityDesc];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(name = %@)", name.text];
[request setPredicate:pred];